# Is it okey to keep subcomponents in an array and search a component by using it's props?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a table in my React app.

Container component (TableComponent) will keep all of the subcomponents (CellComponent) and I need to access a sub component with a unique value kept in subcomponent.

Is it a bad practice to try to access a subcomponent by searching the array of subcomponents and removing it from container component's state?

```
const TableComponent = props => {
  const [cellArray, setCellArray] = useState(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(uniqueValue => (
      <CellComponent dataHolder={new CellData(uniqueValue)} />
    )),
  )
  function findComponentAndRemoveFromCellComponentList(idValue) {
    let cellComponentElement = cellArray.find(
      x => x.props.dataHolder.uniqueValue == idValue,
    )
    //remove cellComponentElement from cellArray
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>{cellArray}</div>
      <div>
        {' '}
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            findComponentAndRemoveFromCellComponentList('someValue')
          }
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: In the future, please format your code, and make sure it compiles before posting. I fixed it this time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a bad practice. Your parent shouldn't need to inspect the props of its children... it supplied the props to begin with.

Instead of anonymously initializing `CellData`, map your ids to `CellData` first, then search through those. In other words, don't store components as "owners" of data; determine the data to pass down, and manipulate that data directly. Something like:

```
const TableComponent = props => {
  const [cellData, setCellData] = useState(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(uniqueValue => new CellData(uniqueValue)),
  )

  function findComponentAndRemoveFromCellComponentList(idValue) {
    setCellData(cellData.filter(value => value.uniqueValue !== idValue))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {cellData.map(dataHolder => (
          <CellComponent dataHolder={dataHolder} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => findComponentAndRemoveFromCellComponentList(4)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the point you mentioned and thanks for the correction about post.